# Passing a folder of files into a PS1 script via CMD

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to convert some ASCII files via the command shell (Windows 11).
I have come across an old script and command-line which should do this.

The command goes like this:
dir *.j2w | & d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1

I get the following error message:
"& was unexpected at this time."

So I'm thinking the error is in the command line, as there is no ampersand character inside the script.

Any commandline gurus know what I could try next?

```
    Create MapInfo TAB files from TFW files
December 17, 2010 codecontemplator Leave a comment Go to comments
A simple powershell script to create .tab files from .tfw files. Inspiration from http://free-zg.t-com.hr/gorantt/geo/tfw2tab.htm.

# sample usage: dir *.j2w | & d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1

param($coordsys = "CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 117, `”m`”, 173, 0, 0.9996")

process
{
# ref: http://free-zg.t-com.hr/gorantt/geo/tfw2tab.htm

# parse coefficients from .j2w file
$j2w = Get-Content $_
$dx = [double]$j2w[0];
$dy = [double]$j2w[3];
$x0 = [double]$j2w[4];
$y0 = [double]$j2w[5];

# calculate additional points for .tab file
$x1 = $x0 + $dx
$y1 = $y0
$x2 = $x0
$y2 = $y0 + $dy

# figure out filenames for target
$tab = $_.FullName.SubString(0, $_.Fullname.Length - $_.Extension.Length) + ".tab"
$jp2 = $_.Name.SubString(0, $_.Name.Length - $_.Extension.Length) + ".jp2"

# create tab file content
$text = @"
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
File "jp2"
Type "RASTER"
($x0,$y0) (0,0) Label "Pt 1",
($x1,$y1) (1,0) Label "Pt 2",
($x2,$y2) (0,1) Label "Pt 3"
$coordsys
Units "m"
"@

# create tab file and set content
new-item -path $tab -type file -force -value $text
}
```

Comment: To send data from source to destination, you have to tell to do so, via the Set-Content cmdlet, or PowerShell redirect command.  Many special characters have special meanings/use in PowerShell. The ```&``` is a special operator, that is known as the ***Call operator***, used to launch/start commands. The ```|```, the pipel one is to pass code from one side to the other.. You are passing many files so that needs a loop to process the dataset. You are trying to pass a collection to a call/launch command with that code, and that is not correct. What you show needs more detail. List the .ps1 text.

Comment: Will edit my post to show the ps1 content.

Comment: Thanks, for up dating your post, but the errors is not caused by the .ps1. The error is caused by that command. This ```dir *.j2w | & d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1``` is just wrong. It is the ```&```, in there that causes the error. YOu have to have a loop to iterate over a collection.  ***See the PS help files for using loops and collections.*** This ````dir *.j2w``` is returning one file at a time, and this ```| & d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1``` is to process one file at a time, thus you must loop this. You cannot use the pipeline ```|``` this way. As that's not valid syntax.

Comment: In that case I'd like to try a batch file (something.bat) that processes files as follows:
Would that work do you think? 

    file01.j2w | d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1

    file02.j2w | d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1

    file03.j2w | d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1

Comment: You got this 13 year old code from here: ***https://danielbrannstrom.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/create-mapinfo-tab-files-from-tfw-files/*** and even the author of this code says, at the bottom of the page, 
   ***EDIT: Do not use this code. Download the latest version from http://mapinfotools.codeplex.com instead.***;   even that site link is no longer valid. All that text at the top of that script must be commented out or deleted.  MapInfo is a very old GIS product ( I used it decades ago). I didn't even think that company was still around. But I guess they are. ;-}

Comment: Try following : Get-ChildItem -Path *.j2w | foreach { d:\tempwork\j2w-2-tab.ps1 $_.FullName}

Comment: Tried that, but it needs more I think. I put powershell in front of Get-ChildItem but then the command interpreter sees 'foreach' and fails. It needs to stay with powershell so cmd doesn't try to run it. I tried "" around it but it still errors.